# Get term value from user field and set that value to new field

Tags: 7, entities

How to get term from user field and set that to the field in node?
When user is creating node I need to get term and set it to the node field.

I have field_term_reference in user fields and in node I have field_book_reference field. I need to get term from field_term_reference and set that term to the field_book_reference.

Both fields has autocomplete widget.

Here is my current non-working code:

```
function set_value_node_presave($node) {
global $user;
$user = user_load($user->uid);
$term = field_get_items($user, $account, 'field_term_reference');

$node->field_book_reference[$node->language][0]['value'] = $node->$term;

}
```

**SOLVED** Here is working code:

```
function set_value_node_presave($node) {
global $user;
$user = user_load($user->uid);
// Get field from user
$term = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_term_reference');

$node->field_book_reference[$node->language][0]['tid'] = $term[0]['tid'];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$node->$term` definitely isn't what you want. Taxonomy references are stored by `tid`, so

```
$node->field_book_reference[$node->language][0]['tid'] = $term[0]['tid'];
```

should work